# JWT - Verify Token given a public key

Tags: genexus

I need to create a Rest API that receives a JWT token and I need to validate it with a given public key.

> "They must validate the "Bearer Token" sent in the header of
> requests using a public key provided according to the environment, as well as verifying the
> scope user availability. Consult "

The public key:
http://desenv.authenticador.sp.gov.br/.well-known/jwks

I tried using [DoVerify()](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43989,JWT%20Creator) but I don't know where to enter the public key.

```
&token = &HttpRequest.GetHeader('Authorization')
if not &token.IsEmpty() 
    &token = &token.Replace("Bearer ", "")  
    &result = &JWTCreator.DoVerify(&token, JWTAlgorithm.RS256, &privateClaims, &JWTOptions) 
    if &result              
        &mensagem = 'token is valid'
    else
        &mensagem = "token is NOT valid"
        If &JWTCreator.HasError()
            &codigo = &JWTCreator.GetErrorCode().ToNumeric()
            &mensagem = &JWTCreator.GetErrorDescription()
        EndIf   
    endif
else
   &codigo = 401
   &mensagem = "Token not found!"
endif
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a token, use that in jet.io to encode the first part of the key. Is the jwt token created by your application? - if so then you probably might have included a public key in the first part of the jwt token.

Comment: No, the token I get is generated by another application, they provide a public key to validate the token received in my API. Is it possible with genexus?

Comment: The framework you are using should be able to parse the token and extractClaims , you need to check that documentation. I  have used jwt in Spring boot app, there the public key can be retrieved by parsing the jwt token. Hope fully that is base64 hash algorithm. The JWT token is three part content split by '.' the first part has the public key, copy complete token info in jwt.io and you might get the header info in decoded area where you could see the public key.  Simply in the code extract the body, and compare the parsed string with the public key you have.

Answer (score 0):

Load the certificate using the [Certificate type](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43920,Certificate). The function will depend on the format of the cert.

Then, [add it](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43983,JWT%20Optional%20Data#SetCertificate) to the `JWTOptions`

Also, it looks like the [`DoVerifyJustSignature`](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?43989,JWT%20Creator#DoVerifyJustSignature) is the function you want to use in that case.

Comment: thanks for answering. I've been working with the JWT module but I haven't had success with the DoVerify() method.

My function is to validate the token header, I got it using the GetHeader() method.

I still have another task which is to validate the token expiration. I can get the expiry date via the GetPayload() method. But the times are in UNIX format.

I believe the DoVerify() method does exactly these validations, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follows:

A procedure that expects a token and returns a code and a message.

```
parm(in:&jwt_token, out:&codigo, out:&mensagem);
```

Source:

```
&codigo = 0
&mensagem = ''
if not &jwt_token.IsEmpty() and &jwt_token.Contains('Bearer')
    &token = &jwt_token.Replace("Bearer ", "")
    
    // capturar o payload do token e o header para comparar com o que temos na chave publica.
    &payload = &JWTCreator.GetPayload(&token)   
    &header = &JWTCreator.GetHeader(&token)
    // carregar o payload e header no SDT.
    &SDTJWTOptions.header.FromJson(&header)
    &SDTJWTOptions.payload.FromJson(&payload)   
    
    // Validar se o token é compátivel com a chave publica disponibilizada.
    &ChavePub_SDTJWTOptions.header.FromJson('{"typ": "JWT","alg": "RS256","x5t": "vST_OxZ0TJ5w3miLGWJ7xlH8sZo","kid": "vST_OxZ0TJ5w3miLGWJ7xlH8sZo"}')      
    If (&SDTJWTOptions.header.alg <> &ChavePub_SDTJWTOptions.header.alg) or
       (&SDTJWTOptions.header.typ <> &ChavePub_SDTJWTOptions.header.typ) or 
       (&SDTJWTOptions.header.x5t <> &ChavePub_SDTJWTOptions.header.x5t) or     
       (&SDTJWTOptions.header.kid <> &ChavePub_SDTJWTOptions.header.kid)        
        &codigo = 401
        &mensagem =  "Token Inválido!" // existe um Bearer Token inválido;
        Return
    EndIf   
    // Validar se o token está com a data de expiração válida.
    // A data do token é em formato UNIX que faz necessário a conversão.
    // - Data UNIX inicia em 1/1/1970 as 00:00:00
    // - Com a data UNIX formatada, adicionar a expiração em UNIX  como segundos.
    &Datetime = YMDHMStoT(1970, 1, 1, 00, 00, 00)
    &NowDatetime = ServerNow()
    &TokenDatetime = &Datetime.AddSeconds(&SDTJWTOptions.payload.exp)
    // Valida se o retorno da diferença das datas (atual vs token) é menor que 0,
    // indicando que a data de expiração já passou e é inválida.
    &Diff = &TokenDatetime.Difference(&NowDatetime)
    If &Diff <= 0
        &codigo = 401
        &mensagem = "Token Expirado!" // existe um Bearer Token válido, porém está expirado;        
    EndIf
    

Else
    
    &codigo = 401
    &mensagem = "Requisição sem token de autorização" // não encontrado o Bearer Token no header;
    
EndIf
Return
```